# How to set object values to autocomplete text-value in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

[
{
"id": 1,
"start_time": "10:00",
"end_time": "11:30",
"active": true
}emphasized text
]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working demo.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return {
    selectedItems: [],
      items: [ { "id": 1, "start_time": "10:00", "end_time": "11:30", "active": true },{ "id": 2, "start_time": "11:30", "end_time": "01:00", "active": true }]
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-autocomplete
              v-model="selectedItems"
              :items="items"
              filled
              chips
              color="blue-grey lighten-2"
              label="Select"
              item-text="start_time"
              item-value="id"
              multiple
            >
              <template v-slot:selection="data">
                <v-chip
                  v-bind="data.attrs"
                  :input-value="data.selected"
                >
                  {{ data.item.start_time }} ~ {{data.item.end_time}}
                </v-chip>
              </template>
              <template v-slot:item="data">
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>{{ data.item.start_time }} ~ {{data.item.end_time}}</v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
              </template>
            </v-autocomplete>
  </v-app>
</div>
```